# Stripe API Status 200 OK No Event Created

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, api, stripe-payments

I am utilizing the Stripe API with a test key. I have the payment form successfully posting to the Stripe API endpoint, however no event is being created. When I check the Stripe Event/Logs I am able to see a 200 - Ok success message under the logs tab for my submitted test payment, however the events tab remains empty. Can't seem to figure this out. My code is below.

Here is my php for processing payment:

```
function wpay_stripe_process_payment() {
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'stripe' && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['stripe_nonce'], 'stripe-nonce')) {

        global $stripe_options;

        // load the stripe libraries
        require_once(STRIPE_BASE_DIR . '/lib/Stripe.php');

        // retrieve the token generated by stripe.js
        $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

        // check if we are using test mode
        if(isset($stripe_options['test_mode']) && $stripe_options['test_mode']) {
            $secret_key = $stripe_options['test_secret_key'];
        } else {
            $secret_key = $stripe_options['live_secret_key'];
        }

        // attempt to charge the customer's card
        try {
            Stripe::setApiKey($secret_key);
            $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
                    'amount' => 1000, // $10
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                    'card' => $token
                )
            );


            // redirect on successful payment
            $redirect = add_query_arg('payment', 'paid', $_POST['redirect']);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // redirect on failed payment
            $redirect = add_query_arg('payment', 'failed', $_POST['redirect']);
        }

        // redirect back to our previous page with the added query variable
        wp_redirect($redirect); exit;
    }
}
add_action('wpay_stripe_process_payment');
```

Here is my js for sending the payment info:

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey(stripe_vars.publishable_key);

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    if (response.error) {
        // show errors returned by Stripe
        jQuery(".payment-errors").html(response.error.message);
        // re-enable the submit button
        jQuery('#stripe-submit').attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        var form$ = jQuery("#stripe-payment-form");
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response['id'];
        // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "'/>");
        // and submit
        form$.get(0).submit();
    }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#stripe-payment-form").submit(function(event) {
        // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $('#stripe-submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        // send the card details to Stripe
        Stripe.createToken({
            number: $('.card-number').val(),
            cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
            exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
            exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
        }, stripeResponseHandler);

        // prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
    });
});
```

JSON response:

```
{
  "id": "tok_1B12dQG6oQhg3oEDNlZLFORy",
  "object": "token",
  "card": {
    "id": "card_1B12dQG6oQhg3oEDIQa4fiCe",
    "object": "card",
    "address_city": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "brand": "Visa",
    "country": "US",
    "cvc_check": "unchecked",
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 4,
    "exp_year": 2018,
    "funding": "credit",
    "last4": "4242",
    "metadata": {
    },
    "name": null,
    "tokenization_method": null
  },
  "client_ip": "187.232.128.105",
  "created": 1505177536,
  "livemode": false,
  "type": "card",
  "used": false
}
```

Comment: Can you add the JSON response in the 200 - OK log?

Comment: @spartacus I've updated the post with the JSON response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you are not providing the right key for your token, according to the Stripe documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/charges

This:

```
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    'amount' => 1000, // $10
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'card' => $token // I think the key here needs to be "source"
));
```

Should be this:

```
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    'amount' => 1000, // $10
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'source' => $token
));
```

And for me, I'm using the Stripe PHP library that they provide, and instead of:

```
Stripe_Charge::create(...);
```

I'm using:

```
\Stripe\Charge::create(...);
```

But really I think the issue might be that you need to use "source", not "card" when doing your charge.

Answer (score 1):

Your Stripe token is at `response.id`, not `response['id']`:

```
// token contains id, last4, and card type
var token = response.id;
```

The response is a JSON object, so you have to traverse the object like you would any other js object.

Comment: Actually, response['id'] works just fine. I use it this way without issue.

Comment: I've had the Stripe API on my frontend fail using bracket notation. However, I think your answer may have hit the true issue. It should be (in PHP) 'source', not 'card'. Upvoting your answer.

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it, it should be response.id. Even the Stripe docs show it that way. I upvoted you too. It's relevant, and should be addressed.